# JQUERY in .NET 1.1 -- Loading Message

Tags: .net, jquery

I am a newbie to JQUERY.. I want to use it in .NET 1.1 application. When a button is clicked it takes long time to populate the results on to my control .. I want to show " loading ..please wait" message to the user..

How can I achieve this ??

Answer (score 2):

This could help you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var loading = $('#loadingPlaceholder');

    $('#somebutton').click(function(){
        $(loading).html('loading');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test.html',
            success: function(){
                $(loading).html('');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Probably better than my answer in the long run.

Comment: Thank You... I don't have AJAX installed on server... how can i do this with out using JAX ?

Answer (score 1):

jquery is a client-side javascript library.  Thus it doesn't matter what version of .NET is running on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking to do is to have an update progress message display. Microsoft Ajax has this already implemented. .Net 1.1 can use the ajax framework and it's very easy to drop an update panel and an update progress control on a page and have the functionality that you're looking for. [Here is a link](http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updateprogress-control/) to a simple example.

[Offical page for MS Ajax](http://www.asp.net/(S(vovsvx454o5rex452c4ypcy3))/ajax/)

[Update Progress Demostration](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/UpdatePanelAnimation/UpdatePanelAnimation.aspx)

Web.config setup:

```
<add tagPrefix="ajax" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" 
                      assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" />
<add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" 
                     assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0,
                     Culture=neutral, 
                     PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

And the DLL's to include in the BIN folder:

```
AjaxControlToolkit.dll
AJAXExtensionsToolbox.dll
```

Good luck and hope this helps some.

Comment: Thank You... But my server doesn't have AJAX installed.. Unless AJAX is installed can't use the <ASP:ScriptManager> and <asp:updatepanel>..

any other ways ?

Comment: It's just two dll's to include with your application in the bin folder and referenced in the web.config. Nothing to install on the server.